# sql query parser --- how to fetch table_name

Tags: python, regex

I have lot of files which have oracle sql statements separated by ;

I want to get table_name from those sql select

essentially sql statment are of 3 types in file

```
 Select * from table1;
select * from ( select * from table9 x inner join table10 y on x.col1=y.col1);
select * from table2,table3 where table2.col1=table3.col1
```

1st one is easy for me as I know little bit of regular expression. How can get the table name for other statement

I will prefer result in

```
 Table1
 table9
 table10
 table2
table3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you like to show us your attemtp to write this specialized SQL Parser/Filter/Grep like tool in Python, it will be fun to help you push it further. Thanks.

Comment: to be honest it on my office computer and i cant access it from my home computer. It is XML file actually from ETL tool. First I parse XML file than I need to parse sql statement. Getting back to sql i just need answer to able scenario and i could fix other things hopefully. if you cant answer that fine cheers

Comment: Hm, we are all coders here to help other coders avoid pitfalls and overcome barriers. Usually not providing a ready made parser or hints to which libraries or plugins to use. Having said that, your sample SQL statements show nicely, that this non-regular language is not an easy parse task, regardless, if you only care for some part in it. The first and the last token in SQL is a breeze, but in between is ... work ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant I understand that . I am looking for regular expression to solve 2 and 3 sql problem . should give the table name for 2 and 3rd

Comment: Ok, others may jump in to RegEx'ularize SQL queries of the above mentioned types - a valid subset usecase - Me, taking the python tag verbatim, suggest to look into `pip install sqlparse` and then `import sqlparse; parsed = sqlparse.parse("SELECT ..."); parsed.tokens` and try the API documentation ... Happy hacking. If only RegEx, please update the question to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: no I cant use sqlparse  since I cant install any library. I am looking for regular expression for 2nd and 3rd sql so that it gives me table_name

Answer (score 0):

Finds a word after *from* or *join* and optionaly another word after comma.

```
>>> for m in re.findall(r'(from|join)\s+(\w+)(,\s*(\w+))?', s):
...     print(m[1])
...     if m[3]:
...         print(m[3])
...         
table1
table9
table10
table2
table3
```